# Fill in the blanks in an array

Tags: php

I have an array which I'd like to show all days of weeks or each month of the year, even if data is 0, is it possible to look inside the array and fill in what's not there?

The data I'm returning from mysql table does not show 0 - details below

[Show values even if empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12659970/show-values-even-if-empty)

So, the following shows months of the year and the count, I'd like to fill in the months which aren't there with i.e. 'Feb' => '0' .. 'Sep' => '0' .. 'Dec' => '0'

Array example:

```
$data = array(
    'Jan' => 12,
    'Mar' => 10,
    'Apr' => 7,
    'May' => 80,
    'Jun' => 67,
    'Jul' => 45,
    'Aug' => 66,
    'Oct' => 23,
    'Nov' => 78,
);
```

Comment: Why don't you make the default value in mysql 0 for each month?

Comment: Also this sounds rather trivial. What have you tried so far? Reading through the list of [PHP's array functions](http://php.net/ref.array) might be useful, too. Apart from that you should show the SQL query as it can be probably done with the query already.

Comment: Also instead of posting a new question - as it seems related to the linked one - you should outline in the previous question why it was not a solution for you.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`array_fill_keys`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill-keys.php) to create a "known good starting point" and then `array_merge` or array addition to incorporate your data.

Example:

```
$data = array_fill_keys(array('Jan', 'Feb', 'etc'), 0);
$data = array('Feb' => 40) + $data;
```

Caveat: the result will not end up being ordered by month.

Answer (score 2):

First of all create a blank array with default 0 value than merge this array to your original array.

```
$data = array(
    'Jan' => 0,  
    'Feb' => 0,
    'Mar' => 0,
    'Apr' => 0,
    'May' => 0,
    'Jun' => 0,
    'Jul' => 0,
    'Aug' => 0,
    'Sep' => 0,
    'Oct' => 0,
    'Nov' => 0,
    'Dec' => 0;
);

$data2 = array(
    'Jan' => 12,
    'Mar' => 10,
    'Apr' => 7,
    'May' => 80,
    'Jun' => 67,
    'Jul' => 45,
    'Aug' => 66,
    'Oct' => 23,
    'Nov' => 78,
);

$newarray=array_merge($data, $data2);
```

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out in [the previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12659970/show-values-even-if-empty), you need create some kind of "lookup table" for the month names. If you do not do that within the database, you need to do it in PHP. Such a "table" could be an array of month names:

```
$months = array(
    'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 
    'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'
);
```

You can then iterate over the month names an pick the number if it exists in the result *or* you take the default value:

```
$default = 0;
foreach ($months as $month) {
    $value = isset($data[$month]) ? $data[$month] : $default;
    # $value now contains the month value
    ...
}
```

This should just work.

Take care that the month names that the database returns need to be the same you use in your `$months` array.